# Git: push for teamwork, then rebase for integration

Tags: git, push, rebase

I am working on a project managed with Git with about 20 people divided into teams.  The project managers require that all of the working branches are not just merged into master, but are rather rebased onto master and then merged by the managers themselves.

According to the information I found so far, you should not rebase commits which have already been made publicly available (i.e. pushed to remote) - I already had to deal with this and it wasn't fun.  However, I would really like to share the code with my team before requesting for it to be merged to master (i.e. before rebasing onto master and waiting for the project managers to fast-forward master to reflect our branch).

What is the proper workflow where my team can push to and pull from a remote and then rebase to master for integration?  Is it something simply I'm doing consistently wrong or is it a legitimate problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you rebase before the merge? What’s the sense behind that?

The correct workflow is to not rebase. If your managers want control over the merge into master, but do not want to resolve any merge conflicts, you should just merge master into your topic branch first. “Merging” into master will now once again be a fast-forward operation.

Here is a nice explanation of why rebase is bad: http://geekblog.oneandoneis2.org/index.php/2013/04/30/please-stay-away-from-rebase

If your managers are stubborn, and force you to rebase, there is no really nice solution – this is not what rebase was made for. In that situation, I would:

- share the branch with the team
- contact them before the rebase and make sure that everybody has pushed all their changes (that sounds easy from your description, as the rebase is only done once all the work is done?)
- pull
- rebase
- contact everyone that still wants to work on that branch to run `git fetch`, followed by `git reset --hard origin/branch`, so they get your rebased version.